# How to change the bash prompt of a spawned child bash? Specifically a docker shell

Tags: bash, docker

We've created a custom version of [docker's quickstart script](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/dfb77906b7c7099f2ca8f11633ea4674fe376b77/osx/mpkg/quickstart.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh) that is mostly identical. One further customization we'd like to make is to change the prompt to clearly indicate when you are in a docker configured shell:

`(docker) ~/src/code $`

The script spawns a child shell like this:

```
eval $($DOCKER_MACHINE env $VM --shell=bash)

USER_SHELL=$(dscl /Search -read /Users/$USER UserShell | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1)
if [[ $USER_SHELL == *"/bash"* ]] || [[ $USER_SHELL == *"/zsh"* ]] || [[ $USER_SHELL == *"/sh"* ]]; then
  $USER_SHELL --login
else
  $USER_SHELL
fi
```

I can easily change my host prompt with `export PS1="(docker)$"` but am having difficulty getting such a change into the spawning child shell.

I've tried `$USER_SHELL --login --noprofile -c "export PS1='(docker)'"`

No luck.

Comment: Login shell clears the environment, except `HOME`, `SHELL`, `PATH`, `TERM`, `LOGNAME`, and `USER`. If you don't have a strong reason to run the shell as login shell, you might as well just remove the `--login` option.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Really? `export FOO=5; bash --login`; then `echo $FOO`. Still prints 5. As far as I know, the only difference between a login shell and a "regular" shell is that it sources a different file on startup.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm wrong. Ignore my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-c` option causes the shell to execute the given string, then *exit*. Instead, you can add the desired value of `PS1` to the interactive shell with

```
PS1='...' $USER_SHELL --login --noprofile
```

(In general, you don't need to export `PS1`. It is only used by the shell itself, not by any child processes. Any child shells configure their prompt from their configuration files, which is why you need `--noprofile` to prevent it from overriding the prompt you are providing from "outside".)